# Should professors intervene if a student is wearing offensive clothing in their classroom?

Tags: professorship, harassment, outward-appearance

A [question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/17718/campus-dress-codes-for-a-student-in-university) about university dress codes reminded me of an incident that happened when I was an undergrad, in which a classmate came to school wearing a really offensive and **misogynistic** t-shirt.

I was *extremely* uncomfortable, especially since this was an engineering program and I was one of only three or four female students in a class of about fifty. I had another class with the same student later that day and he was still wearing the shirt. I remember wishing at the time that a faculty member or *someone* with more authority than me would do something about it.

So, my question is as follows:

- Should a professor intervene if a student in their class is wearing clothing that is likely to be offensive and hostile to other students? If so, how?
- If yes: are there any scenarios in which a professor should *not* do anything even though a student's clothes contains material that is hostile towards another student or group of students?

And finally,

- If I come across this scenario as a TA, in which a student (who may be a peer in my program of study) in my class is wearing something offensive, what can I do about it? I don't feel comfortable (or safe, for that matter) as a woman confronting a male student about an item of clothing that is offensive to women. On the other hand, I feel like it is my responsibility to keep a non-hostile environment in my classroom.

**Discriminatory harassment** is forbidden by the university's code of conduct and includes: placing written or graphic material which demeans or shows hostility or aversion toward an individual or group because of race, color, religion, gender, national origin, age or disability.

The item of clothing in question contained a slogan and image that is indubitably demeaning and hostile towards women.

Comment: Doesn't this really depend upon the free speech laws of that particular country and/or specific university/college dress codes? If that particular attire is against any of these principles, then a professor may object, otherwise, I don't see why the professor/TA should care.

Comment: @Shion The attire certainly violates university policy on discriminatory harassment, and the professor should care if his classroom is a hostile environment to some students.

Comment: Why is something automatically hostile if it is an unpopular view? Free speech laws are specifically meant to protect unpopular and minority views. If all that this student is doing is wearing a t-shirt with a message, then I don't think this should be automatically construed as being discriminatory/hostile.

Comment: Having said this, I think that if you feel that concerned then you should definitely report this incident to the administration and let them deal with it. Specific to the US, many such similar cases with free speech and clothing messages have been struck down by Federal Appeals Courts on grounds of violating the First Amendment and many such cases are now making the rounds of the justice system.

Comment: @Shion Discriminatory harassment: "Written or graphic material which demeans or shows hostility or aversion toward an individual or group because of race, color, religion, **gender**, national origin, age or disability"

Comment: There are some very interesting case laws in the US Court system about this since it falls in the twilight zone between absolute free speech and the need to balance an anti-discriminatory environment. The Supreme Court has _not_ issued an final judgment regarding this issue but scholars except this to be decided with some finality in the next 10 years.

Comment: I don't really see how free speech comes into play here. The first amendment in the US is about the GOVERNMENT not restricting freedom of expression. If for example this is a private school, then there are no blanket free speech exemptions. In any case, that's not the question being asked.

Comment: Even if the school is public, it does not mean that the classroom is a public space that anyone has a right to (i) occupy and (ii) speak unrestrictedly in.  For instance you need to stop talking when the instructor asks you to.  Failure to behave appropriately in the classroom (as determined by university policy and the instructor) is grounds for being dismissed from the classroom and, if the behavior is especially flagrant and/or repeated, the course.

Comment: There's no information in the post that the offense has happened in US, so refering to US laws seems premature. However, there's also missing important information of the character of the t-shirt, only the interpretation from the OP. It will make a big difference if it was really some **mysogynic** text (hate speach, threat of violence/extermination) or only OP has interpreted it as hostile.

Comment: @Łukasz웃Lツ I believe it would not be constructive to post an offensive slogan on this site, even for illustrative purposes.

Comment: @ff524 it's important for people to know what they are talking about... At least you should specify the class of the text. Using the word **mysogynic**, one could suppose it's the hate speach, so it calls to violence or extermination, or to removing women from society. However, AFAIK, mysogynic ideas came only from old, embittered thinkers, and are unlikely to be seen on someone's T-Shirt. I've heard about androgynous organization (general hate towards mankind, in single case hate against men).

Comment: @Łukasz웃Lツ You can ask about this on meta; if the consensus there is that it's OK to post this message for illustrative purposes, I will. Otherwise, I won't.

Comment: @Łukasz웃Lツ Also: **harassment/misogyny is not restricted to "violent" messages that call for physically harming women.**

Comment: @ff524 you don't have to post the message, but you shouldn't leave the place for misinterpretations too. If the message really calls for killing, your collegue may be potential candidate for massacre, so calling police/FBI/military/whoever would be recommended ASAP. However, it's hard to say without knowing the amount of hate in the message. Well, assuming you're living in country where guns are easily available. This also makes a difference. On the other side, hate/aversion to women may be a symptom of heavy depression, that could result in suicide attempts etc.

Comment: @Łukasz웃Lツ I said the "item of clothing in question contained a slogan and image that is indubitably demeaning and hostile towards women" - I don't consider that subject to misinterpretation, unless you think I don't know how to identify something that is demeaning and hostile towards women.

Comment: Double-standard check: I'm curious if the you would have been just as offended if the genders were swapped.

Comment: @AaronHall You mean if a woman was wearing the misogynistic shirt? Or a woman was wearing a misandric shirt? I probably wouldn't have felt personally traumatized in the second case, but I still think an authority figure should intervene.

Comment: @AaronHall Silliness check: I'm curious if there is any evidence of anything remotely similar happening with any regularity if the genders were swapped. Also, that still wouldn't be equivalent.

Comment: I'm not really sure the outcome should hinge on whether the people here believe that the display was "sufficiently misogynistic" or not. Why not just take as stipulated that it indeed was: the question is really about what to do next, and that's a reasonable question to ask.

Comment: Not to side with your professor who didn't intervene back then, but as someone not growing up in the US and not very well acquainted with the slang culture, I could have been totally oblivious about whatever shirt you're wearing. I believe students who feel offended should contact the TA and professor as well, instead of hoping for an a-ha moment from the professor.

Comment: @Penguin_Knight That is a very good point - the shirt in question used a slang term for male genitalia that is very well-known in the U.S., but might not be known everywhere else.

Comment: This question somewhat obscures the fact that the other students, especially the male ones in case of a misogynistic message, should also intervene. Every adult has a responsibility, and the particular offensive message always puts some demographic on the defensive who know what kind of response they will get if they complain. University students are the same age as employees who are expected not to harass their coworkers.

Comment: Can you provide specifics on the shirt's content, now that you've gotten a good amount of unbiased (in terms of content) feedback?

Comment: @HC_ I believe it would not be constructive to post an offensive slogan on this site, even for illustrative purposes.

Comment: @HC_ Why request every single detail from the OP? We should respect people's choice to be (partially) anonymous, rather then questioning their interpretation because of incomplete details. Question is clear (and even more general) without it. I've opened [a meta question](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/questions/834/people-denying-the-situation-in-the-questions-instead-of-answering) asking, among other things, why every single detail should be needed?

Comment: OP: Ok :). @penelope Just out of curiosity, nothing more. I did not say anything to imply that I was questioning her interpretation, as the question is one of principle; I think it is rather unfair of you to jump to conclusions like that and assume I was questioning OP's interpretation or merit. I just wanted to see what a male engineering student would mistakenly think was OK to wear to class.

Comment: @Hc_ Sorry, didn't mean to seem aggressive. The meta question wasn't open because of your comment, or even just this question. And, the OP did say several times in the comments she believed it not constructive to post an offensive slogan on the site... you probably simply didn't see it before, but after all the turmoil on this question, I was too fast to jump to conclusions. Sorry :/

Comment: This was posted two days ago, so I assume that the incident has come and gone. In this case, I would speak to the prof and have him construct a general email to the class list reminding students about not wearing that type of offensive clothing to the class. If he (or anyone) does it again, then escalate and either i) call security or ii) simply tell the student that their clothing is not appropriate to wear in this class.

Comment: @ff524 Without the content of the slogan in question, anyone attempting to make any judgement on said slogan is left chasing gremlins. This is responsible forum populated by adults capable of discussing the subject matter. No good comes from obfuscation.

Comment: @Travis: But the question is *not* about making a judgment on the slogan, and I think it is wise for the OP to leave it unsaid specifically to prevent this discussion from turning into evaluation of the slogan. The question is what to do next, assuming for the sake of question that the slogan is indeed sufficiently hostile. (This forum may indeed consist of "adults capable of discussing the subject matter", but as the subject matter is *not* the slogan, it is in some doubt whether the adults are capable of recognizing the subject matter in the first place. :-) )

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Yes, I realized the mistake as I was looking at some of the answers. I think the confusion stems from the idea that the question on the page may not be the question being asked, but this forum is for answering the question on the page, so I accept my earlier comment is irrelevant.

Comment: I apparently don't have enough rep to answer protected questions, so I'll just leave this here. I think professors should have broad authority and discretion to decide whether or not someone gets to wear something in their classroom, *based on whether or not the clothing is consistent with the class's objectives,* and the school should back him up.  It doesn't have to be offensive, it just has to be **a distraction** (transparent tops, gangsta jeans that fall down to the knees and asses hanging out of the bottom of shorts also fit into this category).

Comment: "don't feel comfortable (or safe, for that matter) as a woman confronting a male student about an item of clothing that is offensive to women." -- specifically on this point, your employer has a responsibility to help you to handle (and learn to handle) dicey situations in the classroom. Quite aside from their duty of care to you, if you're not comfortable enforcing their rules when acting as their representative, then they have a problem. Knowing the attitude of the organization, its procedures and back-up plans may make you more comfortable. At least you can get informal advice from others.

Comment: ... and if it (sadly) turns out that the organization *doesn't* have procedures and support in place for TAs in such situations, then at least you know for sure not to take a risk. I would hope that this is fairly rare, but it might depend on the country and even on the specific people running particular universities or departments.

Comment: Dear @ff524, I find fully legitimate your fear of repercussions of direct confrontation of this individual as an offended minority. However I feel the responsibility of any authority figure to uphold the credo of the university in no way diminishes your right and duty as an offended individual to raise your concerns to the proper authorities, which you have not. Surely the Discriminatory Harrassment clause you quoted gives you a case and you will have supporters in your TA's and professors should you seek them out.But you should play a more active role in securing your rights as clearly stated

Comment: What does that mean N-word, C-word, F-word, etc?

Comment: @user781 They are censored forms of offensive words. The following links go to the wikipedia page of the uncensored page:  [N-word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nigger), [C-word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cunt), [F-word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuck)

Comment: @Suresh There is no such thing as a "Right to not be offended", from the government nor from any institution I'm aware of. Unless the University had an explicit policy against the clothing that person chose to wear, then there's little OP (or anyone) could actually do about it. Sometimes, it's just easier, and best, to grow a thick skin.

Comment: ff524 You say "I don't consider that subject to misinterpretation, unless you think I don't know how to identify something that is demeaning and hostile towards women".  Unfortunately there's no consensus reality on this one, so I wouldn't take @HC_ 's curious question personally.  E.g. many apparently serious and otherwise-reasonable-sounding people believe any sexual intercourse between a man and a woman is demeaning and hostile towards women.  Anyway, as has been pointed out, that isn't the point, and I agree with you that posting the slogan here would be counterproductive.

Comment: @penelope Two years later, I better understand why this question is better served without a specific example (image) :) (better late than never!?)

Comment: Given the recent events around Jordan B. Peterson in Canada and the ridiculous directions the events in Evergreen College surrounding Bret Weinstein are taking in the last couple days, I'm genuinely worried by the lack of principled commitment to free speech that finds so much support in this thread here. Forget the legal technicalities whether wearing an "I hate niggers" shirt to class is covered by a constitutional right to free speech - free speech has to be upheld as long the teacher can reasonably talk/present and his lecture remains audible/visible to the students.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

As an instructor -- or a TA, or whoever is leading a formalized academic session -- you have not only the right but some responsibility to enforce at least minimal standards of acceptable behavior.  Some behavior is borderline and you do want to look to the other people in the room to see whether it is bothering them.  Some behavior really isn't, e.g. discriminatory harassment as mentioned above.  In particular if a student wears a tee shirt bearing what is clear to you is a slur related to

- Race, ethnicity, skin color ([examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ethnic_slurs) include the n-word)
- Sexuality ([general examples](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:English_sexual_slurs))

  - Homophobia ([examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Homophobic_slurs) include the f-word)
  - Misogyny ([examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Misogynistic_slurs) include the c-word)
- Religion ([examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_religious_slurs))
- ***Any*** other group or person

then as an instructor you should get them to leave right away.  You say that you don't feel "safe" confronting a male student about this.  This concerns me a little bit, as you are an authority figure even as a TA and especially as an instructor.  If you are not willing to enforce your authority directly then I think you need to have alternate arrangements in mind that will do so: e.g. you could try to call campus security and not continue the class until they arrive.  But I think one should realize that one absolutely has the right, and sometimes the obligation, to ask a student to leave the classroom under certain circumstances.  If I were in this situation and the student were a 250 pound athlete, I would still ask him to leave unless I had some specific intuition that he would react physically or violently to that request.  I don't have to feel like I can physically overpower someone in order to exert authority over them.

Comment: In general I agree with you about having authority even as a TA; but the kind of individual who wears a clearly offensive shirt to school is someone who has questionable judgement, and I'm concerned about confronting someone like that.

Comment: @ff524: Well, of course you have to use your best judgement, and erring a little bit on the side of guaranteeing your own personal safety seems more than understandable.  But you do need to do *something*.  If a student's attire makes you feel that you cannot even reason with them enough to ask them to leave the class, then you have a huge problem with them in the classroom.  It would then be appropriate to suspend or cancel class until the issue is resolved.

Comment: Put a statement in your syllabus reminding students about university policy in this regard, and that inappropriate attire is not allowed. You  should discuss some examples of inappropriate attire (offensive language, revealing clothing, etc.). If you have a problem with a student, male or female, do as Pete suggested in an earlier comment and call security. The university should be more than happy to back you up on this. If they are not, then you have another problem

Comment: @Chris Leary: Yes, right on.  In fact if someone feels like they are going to call for outside assistance as a *first resort*, then it would be wise to set that up in advance: e.g. have the number immediately available on one's cell phone, have a conversation with campus personnel about getting support in situations like this, and so forth.

Comment: @ff524 Are there any male students in the class you are comfortable speaking with? Maybe telling them to speak with [the bad guy] as you "don't think that all people are comfortable with his t-shirt" (alternatively: "such t-shirts are not allowed within the campus") and you "prefer to solve it in an informal way" (without accusing anyone or directly pointing that you are the victim). If there are no such, or it is not successful, I think that there is little choice but to resort to higher authorities (or some other TA or professor, who is not afraid to face [the bad guy]).

Comment: @PiotrMigdal I understand the idea: since I think it would be hard for me (a woman) to confront a guy who believes women have nothing valuable to say, I could ask a man to do it. But if I ask a male _peer_ to do it, I am confirming the stereotypes this guy believes: women need men to fight their battles for them, women can't tell men what to do, etc. I want the intervention to come from a place of legitimate authority, not what this guy sees as "male authority." So I think escalating to a professor or dean is better than going through a peer.

Comment: @ff524 I really don't think that student will physically harass you because that will make matter only worse for him.

Comment: @ff524 I wouldn't care at all what the guy believes (given your other comments about his behaviour; as I understood, your goal was to make the class a safe and comfortable place). My point was to deal it in a way that 1. Does not require more force than needed (I met a _lot_ of semi-autistic science students, who held strong views on some issues, or were oblivious to some "obvious" implication of how their behaviour is perceived, but "please don't" worked on them.) 2. If you are afraid to talk with him in person, they it is also crucial not to make you (or any other) a victim. Safety first.

Comment: @ff524 Personally, I don't like reporting to authorities without giving any warning (with the sole exception of safety OR breaching already explicitly mentioned rules), and trying to deal with problems informally whenever possible. However, I don't know your exact situation, so at this point it is for you to decide. (In any case, it is you to decide, you know the situation, and it is you who's judgement is (most likely) the most appropriate.)

Comment: @ff524 "but the kind of individual who wears a clearly offensive shirt to school is someone who has questionable judgement..." - That way there be dragons. That's quite a (fallacious) blanket statement to make.

Comment: @Travis: I and ff524 and many other academics (as e.g. indicated here) would question the judgement of a student who wore a clearly offensive shirt into a university classroom.  So I don't see the fallacy.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark This is tantamount to saying "That person has different values than I do, therefore they have questionable judgement." It's a bold and usually autocentric claim. "Clearly offensive" is clear only to you and those like you. Bare female faces are "clearly offensive" to fundamental Islamists, while their misogyny is "clearly offensive" to the western world. The fallacy is assuming that you (the self) are a representative member of that which is good, and that those that are different are by definition not good.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark I believe you misunderstood my point. I wasn't taking issue with the reasoning of the statement, but rather the reasoning which led to the premise - a meta-fallacy, if you will. Perhaps I chose my original words incautiously. The universe of concern (for the fallacy) is not OP's statement or the premise of the statement, but process which led to the creation of the premise. I am not rejecting the premise - I am taking one step up and rejecting that logic. The premise of OP's statement is the output of the fallacious logic. The fallacy committed is the Hasty Generalization.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark Aside from the fallacy, to address your last post, OP's distrust in the target's judgement is not, in fact, based on the university's moral code, but rather her own. Further, the statement is based on OP's personal interpretation of both the offending material and the policy. It is entirely possible that the material does not violate the policy, but OP believes it does. The purpose of my comment was to illustrate out that those with different value systems are not necessarily lesser. Regardless, this is not the place for this discussion. Please email me to continue (in my profile)

Comment: @PeteL.Clark I just realized that emails are not visible to other users. Use PseudoSharpie@dispostable.com.

Comment: What if you were on a public campus in Texas? If I was teaching in Texas, I would not ask the student to leave and I would recommend anybody teaching at a public university there not do so. The risk, in my view, is simply too great. Given the advice which has been given to faculty there, I would be extremely cautious. Even if I'm prepared to take the risk, do I have a right to put my students' lives at risk as well? Guns on campus changes the situation radically.

Comment: Pete, please stop misusing the term homophobic.

Answer (score 108):

I'm a bit disappointed at the number of comments from people who say they need to know what the exact statement on this particular T-shirt was so that they can judge whether it was truly misogynistic before answering the question. The question is clear: What is the appropriate response *given that* a student is ``wearing clothing that is likely to be offensive and hostile to other students''? Debating exactly what constitutes misogyny (or any other form of hate speech) is not the point here. Surely a question about whether a particular slogan is offensive would be too localised for academia.se, whereas the question of how the role of professor and/or TA affects how/whether one calls out offensive speech/behaviour/etc is excellent.

A couple of the other answers express surprise/concern at the OP's comment

> I don't feel comfortable (or safe, for that matter) as a woman
>   confronting a male student about an item of clothing that is offensive
>   to women.

Many of the comments on this page illustrate why it can be so hard to call out misogyny as a woman. Women who call out misogyny are regularly accused of being "too sensitive" and told to "lighten up". On this page we've seen people who think they'd be a better judge of whether something is offensive than the person who *actually experienced* it, suggesting it may have been all in her head, refusing to trust her judgement, and claiming that no young people are misogynists. All this just from outlining a story that inspired a general question about calling out offensive behaviour. Is it any wonder that women may find it difficult to confront the person who's actually wearing the offensive T-shirt?

Finally, to actually answer the question:

Most universities should have something like a code of conduct which forbids discriminatory harassment. The one quoted in the question certainly seems to apply to a T-shirt with an offensive slogan. In this case the professor (or any student in the class) would be within their rights to object to the T-shirt. I might say something like "that T-shirt seems to be in violation of the code of conduct; please don't wear it to this class again", ideally in much the same tone as I would say "If I don't have your homework by tomorrow you will get a zero", but I'd say it loudly enough that anyone paying attention could hear. As with any instance of calling out something offensive, I would only do this if I felt safe enough: you should try to create a safe environment in your classroom, but not at the expense of your own safety.

If you don't feel safe or comfortable enough to call out your student (and I can see this happening especially if that student is also your peer), there might be other people you can talk to, for example the professor of the class you're TAing, or the head of the graduate program in your department, or the student's advisor. This might also be helpful if the student does not respond well when you first address them.

Comment: +1. I am disappointed, but not really surprised, at the unwillingness to take my story at face value. I can't count how many times I've heard "Women in STEM are treated just like anyone else no matter what you say you've experienced, because _I've_ never noticed any  discrimination"

Comment: Thank you for leaving this answer.  It is an important contribution.

Comment: I'm disappointed as well. I expected better from academia.se. The only thing I would add to your answer is that a new professor should do a bit of research into campus security when they start. What is the phone number, how long do they take to arrive, what kind of help can you expect, etc. This information may be invaluable if a confrontational situation ever arises.

Comment: Even though I completely agree with what you have written in the first part of the answer, I am reluctant to upvote because it is not related to the question but rather to the (questionable) behavior of the community. For that purpose, I [asked a meta question](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/q/834/4249), concerning this and all other instances of people not answering the question but instead questioning the facts / interpretations as presented by the OP in the question. The second part of your answer is definitely a valid contribution.

Comment: @penelope I think the first part also addresses the question if you add the following sentence to the beginning: "If you choose to speak up, prepare for the possibility of having your motives and your judgment questioned, as they were on this forum."

Comment: A proportional response demands that you know the level of offence that you are responding to. People asking for the wording, etc. are not supporting misogynism or discrimination they are just showing some common sense.  Whether you ask the person to tone it down, leave there and then or don't like it but say nothing, depends entirely on what exactly it says!

Comment: @ff524 "I can't count how many times I've heard "Women in STEM are treated just like anyone else no matter what you say you've experienced, because I've never noticed any discrimination" Would the same apply if a woman wore a shirt in class that said something to the effect that men are all dead beat good-for-nothings? On principal, yes, that person should be asked to leave the room as well, but in practice this transgression would probably go unchallenged. Just pointing out, there is a double standard at play when it comes to potentially inappropriate clothing choices.

Comment: @SnakeDoc I would hope that, yes, that would also be challenged. But do note that the context can exacerbate these kinds of behaviours. There is a difference in effect if the t-shirt is worn in a class which is 90% male (OP's case) or 90% female (your case) as opposed to 50-50 or 90-10. And local and global histories of discrimination also affect the impact. A racist slogan may do more harm in a place with a history of slavery and Jim Crow and in a classroom which is 95% white.

Answer (score 25):

A professor definitely has some shared responsibility for maintaining a harmonious atmosphere in the classroom. Given that the university has a code of conduct in place (as per the edit) it gives the professor some leeway to address the situation. But it might be difficult to do so without some initial prompting from the concerned students (because as a professor I can't claim to know what is likely to be offensive to students).

So to answer question 1, yes, if the issue is brought up or if it's otherwise clear that the T-shirt is disrupting class. As for question 2, it follows that if no one brings up the issue, the professor might not do anything.

If you're a TA, then there must be a professor. In that case, you should bring it up with them. Maybe they can "drop by" by accident when the student comes, and then they can deal with it without needing to imply that you're the one who brought up the issue.

Comment: As an undergrad, I definitely felt much too embarrassed to bring it up to the professor. I was stunned and insulted and just wanted to get out of there, fast. Knowing how I felt at the time, it's hard for me to swallow that the "victim" should be responsible for bringing it up.

Comment: And, the material in question was really not at all "borderline" or subtle - anybody with eyes would know it would be offensive to women.

Comment: I see what you mean. I guess that's where context becomes important. If the T-shirt in question were really horrifying, maybe I'd feel compelled to bring it up even if no student mentioned it.

Comment: *"it's hard for me to swallow that the "victim" should be responsible for bringing it up."*  The problem being that even if it's universally offensive, you may have been the only one that noticed it.  The professor isn't responsible for reading each word visible on each piece of clothing of all the students.  It's not their job.  When a legitimate complaint is brought to them, then they should act, but you can't expect them to act on everything *you* notice unless you also bring it to their attention.

Comment: @AdamDavis I don't expect someone to intervene about something they have not seen, or don't understand is offensive. Suresh's answer makes a distinction between whether or not someone complained to the professor or otherwise made it obvious that they're bothered, which I don't agree with, because the victim may feel too intimidated or upset to express their discomfort

Comment: @ff524 perhaps time has made things seem worse, but it's difficult to imagine any words printed anywhere being so offensive that one feels compelled to run away in horror. If anything, most folks just mentally note how crass this individual is, and remember that in the future. You will never be able to stop people from offending you - and your sense of offense is likely different from other people's. Sure, everyone should feel comfortable, but sometimes you are just going to be more sensitive to something that's not a huge deal overall (you survived, and perhaps are a better person afterward).

Comment: I find it unfortunate that all sides of the discussion in this comment thread seem to accept that only students' reactions matter -- that, if the OP is the only one to be "offended", then the shirt is fine and OP's discomfort is irrelevant.

Answer (score 22):

Should professors intervene? Yes. Now, I think there's a level of personal judgement to be made here. Some people might overlook certain shirts. Some might think certain types of shirts are more offensive than they really are (ex: someone who's vegetarian might not like [this shirt](http://site.shirtmandude.com/pot-leaf-vegetarian-t-shirt-sq.jpg) and I'd personally wonder if they have a sense of humor).

So, as discussed above, the "you can't go wrong" points are for race/national origin, gender, religion, and sexual orientation, age, and disability.

If I were a teacher (professor or a TA) and I identified something (or it was brought to my attention by a student) that someone is wearing an offensive shirt, then I would probably start by taking the student aside and letting them know that their shirt is offensive to some people, and that it displays remarks that make others uncomfortable, and that the student should not wear that shirt (and others like it) to this class again.

I would do this in private mostly because I don't feel that there's really a lot of benefit to publicly shaming someone who chose such a shirt - maybe they're a new first-year student who hasn't quite learned appropriate behavior yet, or maybe they're going through a phase, or maybe they just didn't think when they put the shirt on because they were drunk one night in Vegas when going T-shirt shopping. Give them a chance to improve. If they never wear the shirt again to class, to me that's a win.

If it happens again then I would not hesitate to walk up to the student after lecture starts and say quietly, "We discussed that you were not to wear shirts like this in class. Did you understand me last time? Do you think that this shirt is appropriate?" If the student isn't able to change the shirt or cover it up then I'd ask him to leave the class and then at that point would make an announcement about appropriate shirts.

Finally, if you are someone who is made uncomfortable by a shirt that someone is wearing then you should tell someone about it. Don't hold it in. Unfortunately lecturers generally only have control of their classroom (for example it's hard for a faculty member to kick someone out of a building, generally) but things like this can be reported.

Comment: *"someone who's vegetarian might not like this shirt.."*  Heh, heh.. nice, but I prefer [this one](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=388586797942550&set=a.165758496892049.36224.100003737007365&type=1&relevant_count=1) which might offend anyone that holds the Olympics in high regard.  As an aside, my aunt (who is vegetarian but not a smoker) would probably smile/laugh at your example.

Answer (score 18):

> Should a professor intervene if a student in their class is wearing clothing that is likely to be offensive and hostile to other students?

It depends on the situation, although IMO the answer in this example is yes. People do not have a right not to be offended, and offending people may be a positive thing in an academic environment, where people need to have their assumptions challenged. Nor is hostility, in and of itself, impermissible in a school environment. But:

1. There's a problem with behavior that is offensive toward a group that is underrepresented in the field being studied.
2. There's a problem with hostility that creates reasonable fear in other people, or that inhibits collegial discussion, or that is directed toward an underrepresented group.

For example, if an 18-year-old comes to my classroom in Goth clothing and acts resentful toward the world, it's not a big issue. It's hostile, but it's hostility that isn't a big problem. If a student wears a heavy metal t-shirt with a satanist message on it, it's not a problem because Christians aren't an underrepresented group; they're the dominant group, and it won't hurt them to be exposed to contrary ideas. Ditto for a t-shirt saying "Darwinists burn in Hell."  But in an engineering class, a misogynistic t-shirt creates a hostile environment for women, who are an underrepresented group in engineering. A t-shirt reading "one faggot, one bullet" is also a problem because it could reasonably cause people to be afraid for their safety.

So IMO the t-shirt you describe *is* a problem in the context in which you describe it. The question is then how to handle it. If possible, do your homework and get bureaucratic buy-in before confronting a student about this kind of thing. Otherwise you can end up not being supported by your administration; as we've seen in the answers to this question, reasonable people can disagree about these things. In this situation, I would probably not say anything at all to the student during class. I would then go and have a five-minute conversation with my dean about what school policy is. If it's clear that school policy puts me on strong ground and that my boss will back me up, then I would email the student and say, "Your t-shirt that said X was unacceptable in my classroom for reason Y. I have discussed this with my supervisor and we are in agreement on how school policy applies here. Please do not wear it to class in the future." This private method of handling it lets the student not be embarrassed in front of others (which is a *big* deal to many 18-20 year olds) and makes it unlikely that we'll have a big classroom confrontation that would detract from instruction or possibly put me in physical danger. If the student then shows up wearing the t-shirt again, despite the email, I would tell him to leave class, citing the email warning and chapter and verse as to my authority to kick him out. (In my case, there is a specific provision in the state education code that gives me that authority.) If he refused to leave, I would call Campus Safety.

Comment: Good observations about the range of events in reality...

Comment: This point of view seems completely wrong to me. You are basically saying that whether feeling offended is fine depends on how many other people share your attributes, which is absurd. In my opinion, truly offensive t-shirts (like the "Darwinists burn in hell" t-shirt you give as an example) should be treated in the same way as truly offensive t-shirts that target underrepresented groups. Just because you're a minority doesn't give you a right to needlessly offend the majority in a classroom setting.

Comment: (1) "Darwinists burn in Hell." So this is okay? What if there is only one Darwinist in the class? This is quite possible in some areas and some countries. I think you are merely exposing your own prejudices with this answer. (2)  "... a misogynistic t-shirt creates a hostile environment for women, who are an underrepresented group in engineering", What about a hostile T-shirt to men in a field like Gender Studies where men are under-represented? Is that okay?

Answer (score 11):

If you feel like the clothes that a student is wearing is fostering a less than nurturing atmosphere in your classroom, it is definitely in your best interest to end this. When you're in a STEM field, it's concerning to see a misogynistic message on a shirt and I think you should find a way to end it.

Depending on the content of the shirt, I would debate whether or not I brought it up in front of the rest of the class. If it had some relation to the course and performance, I would have a hard time not bringing it up front-and-center to the class in order to stop any type of stereotype threat that may pervade the course.   My debate on whether to confront during class would be based on thinking about the mentality of the students that are being oppressed in this case and what they may think, whether it be "that student is not wearing that anymore" or "I cannot believe the instructor did not say anything about that shirt," the latter of which was your response in undergrad.

I would stray away from anything that was accusatory or telling the student what to do, but would focus on asking leading questions that explained why it was not appropriate. This approach depends on the personality of instructor and your mileage may vary.

A more neutral thing to bring up to the student would be something about professionalism in the classroom. A discussion on college being about preparing one for a profession and/or higher scholasticism, and then ask the student if the classroom is really an appropriate venue for his wardrobe choice. Really, how to approach the student would depend on your comfort level, the context of the whole situation, and the explicit description of the Non-Discrimination and Anti-Harassment Policy at your university. A higher-up may be able to help with regards to that.

This isn't an answer to your question per se, but I think this raises a good mindset in order to answer this question for yourself.

Comment: "When you're in a STEM field, it's concerning to see a misogynistic message on a shirt and I think you should find a way to end it."  I agree, and I would only add that if you're not in a STEM field then it is also concerning...

Comment: I totally agree. I am just speaking from my perspective and knowledge base on teaching.

Answer (score 10):

I don't get the people trying to suggest a private conversation etc.  The whole point is to restore the confidence of female students to work in a reasonable atmosphere.

This just calls for "You are not wearing this T-shirt to my classes.  Get out and come back once you are wearing something appropriate."  His bad luck if he relied on wearing that shirt through the day.

Don't start class until he's gone, if necessary calling campus security.  Ask the other professors to do likewise when encountering similar material in order to maintain a professional and workable atmosphere, to avoid being considered the only one with standards.

Comment: I agree that I would have felt _much_ less traumatized - even supported! - if _anyone_ (professor, classmate) had publicly affirmed that the behavior is unacceptable.

Comment: There are some risks with this course of action: (1) administrators may not support you; (2) depending on how much of a jerk the student is and how hostile (the student in this example is certainly a major jerk and very hostile), you can end up with a confrontation that disrupts instruction and/or puts you in danger. "Don't start class until he's gone" could be a recipe for wasting 30 minutes of instruction. If you multiply half an hour by, say, 50 people in the room, that's a huge instructional impact.

Comment: @BenCrowell Another risk is the possibility of rewarding attention-seeking behavior, if he's deliberately wearing the shirt to be provocative. There's a tradeoff here. However, even in a scenario where immediate ejection from class is not wise, some public affirmation that the behavior isn't acceptable (like a comment at the beginning of the next class on appropriate attire and being respectful of others) would help foster a supportive atmosphere.

Comment: Sorry, but the OP clearly stated that the school has a non-harrassment policy.  Throwing him out is not a reward of attention-seeking behavior.  Of course, you can also tell him something like "well, I know there are poor sods who derive their pride from being born with a silver spoon in your mouth.  Being proud of being born with a wooden spoon between your legs seems like a step down.  I hope that most here will be proud of having learnt to use a brain between their ears when you finish."

Comment: @ff524: concerning your first comment: so did you talk to someone about the T-shirt, trying to get feedback what others thought about it?

Comment: @BenCrowell: If the situation in class is unacceptable, then stopping the lecture for whatever length, or even stopping it for the day is a good idea. Continuing the lecture under bad circumstances will not be beneficial for the students.

Comment: One reason to have a private conversation is to avoid escalation, all the more because (in my experience) many students are immature, naive, ill-informed, and have scant conception of the impact of their actions on others, nor of the perception others will have of their random statements whether verbal or T-shirt-wise (gasp!). In particular, to come down hard on a 20-year-old whose T-shirt would be undeniably misogynist is an over-reaction. Let me not hesitate to continue ... that misogyny, especially in traditionally misogynist contexts, is bad. But/and then "defuse" by not ... (cont'd)

Comment: ... (cont'd) declaring an ill-considered T-shirt to be any more than a foolish, naive, ill-informed error... easily corrected by not wearing it ever again... "An educational moment", rather than polarizing?

Comment: @paulgarrett I would act on an assumption of good will and ignorance - even if I thought this assumption almost certainly false. Then you can say 'I realise that you don't intend to show hostility towards women in engineering, but your shirt ...' or whatever. If the student is just an idiot, this should work. If the student is socially inept, this provides explicit instructions on how to improve their social interactions in the classroom. If the student is trying to show off/get a laugh/make a scene, it denies them the satisfaction unless they are really prepared to escalate. ...

Comment: ... If they intended to spew hatred, it gives them a chance to have second thoughts while saving face. It is also likely to be relatively low risk in most cases: it doesn't close off any future options. This is compatible with making a general statement in class (or the next class) of the 'I would like to remind everybody that we are hear to learn and everyone has a responsibility to ensure a supportive classroom environment' or whatever. That can send a message of affirmation without 'picking on' anybody. (But don't assume the t-shirt wearer will pick this up.) @ff524

Comment: @cfr Your two-part comment above is really a gem.  I know this came about as a reply to paulgarrett, but I would love to see this made into an answer.

Answer (score 7):

> Should a professor intervene if a student in their class is wearing clothing that is likely to be offensive and hostile to other students? If so, how?

Maybe.

A professor should hold a discussion with a student when that student is in violation of the school's code of conduct.

If the clothing isn't in violation of the school's code of conduct, a professor will have to decide whether asking the student to desist is worthwhile or not.  In some specific situations, asking a student to stop doing something may actually bring about a situation where they start intentionally coming close to, but not quite, violating the university code.  In that case they may be offensive more frequently than they are currently, randomly picking out what to wear each day.

> Are there any scenarios in which a professor should not do anything even though a student's clothes contains material that is hostile towards another student or group of students?

If it isn't against the school's code of conduct, the professor has little room to insist that certain clothing not be worn, but they can request a student stop wearing such clothing.

As above, though, it may actually exacerbate the problem.

> If I come across this scenario as a TA, in which a student (who may be a peer in my program of study) in my class is wearing something offensive, what can I do about it?

We will assume, for the moment, that the clothing in question is not against the school's code of conduct, but it offensive to everyone, in every time, every situation, culture, place, etc.

First I'd evaluate how often it occurs.  Is this student consistently bringing offensive messages to class, or is this a once or twice a semester problem?

Second, I'd evaluate how much it affects the class.  Is the message visible to every student in class throughout the period, printed on the upper back with the student sitting in the front row, or is it hard to see except when the are standing up with arms at their sides, and then only by the instructor?  In either case, does it prevent other students from paying attention, learning, asking appropriate questions?

Third, I'd ask others how they felt about the issue.  Does it actually bother them, and did it bother them before you brought it up? I'd make sure this isn't merely a slight against me only.

Lastly, I'd decide, based on this information, if intervention is necessary. If it poses a significant, frequent problem, then I'd probably bring it up.  If it poses a significant infrequent problem for a few students, I'd probably bring it up.

A simple, "Please don't wear that shirt to this class again," privately and quietly as they walk out of the class might be sufficient for most cases. Some professors excel at public shaming in a simple effective way.  A humorous comment during the lesson referencing the student's poor taste in clothing might dissuade them from wearing similarly offensive clothing.

> I don't feel comfortable (or safe, for that matter) as a woman confronting a male student about an item of clothing that is offensive to women.

That's a real problem.  If they are communicating something, and you, who are in charge of the classroom, choose not to communicate, then who is going to handle the problem?

If you must, get a third person to back you up.  Preferably someone with authority, and make sure the student understands not just that it's inappropriate, but how it makes you feel.  If it's not just offensive, but threatening, to you then you have all the more reason to make your work environment safe.  Tell your instructor that you can't teach a class where students are threatening you, and that you find certain articles of clothing threatening.  Make your case according to the student code of conduct and it'll be that much stronger.

But you really shouldn't take a passive role in your teaching.  You are learning skills now that will benefit you as an educator later, if that's the career you choose, and you need to learn how to do hard things.  This might be one of them.

> On the other hand, I feel like it is my responsibility to keep a non-hostile environment in my classroom.

Not just for the students, but also for yourself.

Comment: _First I'd evaluate how often it occurs_ - I'm still upset thinking about this single incident years later, so I'd argue that if it is seriously hostile content, once is often enough to be a problem.

Comment: It sounds like you were significantly traumatized by this incident.  If the message was that offensive, and so offensive that you can't even post it here, then it sounds like the student should have been *immediately* ejected from class and not allowed to return until they discussed the issue with the appropriate school authorities, possibly facing legal prosecution and expulsion.  Is that your assessment as well?

Comment: I don't know if the best response would have been to stop class and eject him immediately (for the benefit of the other students in the room) or to send him home to change after class (so as not to reward his attention seeking behavior by making a scene). But he definitely shouldn't have been allowed to go through an entire day at school like that.

Comment: @ff524 Note that t-shirts can be worn inside out ...

Answer (score 6):

The word "misogyny" is is not strictly defined, and applied very loosely and emotionally by different people. You may say *I know misogyny when I see it, I know when I'm offended*, but your shirt wearer almost certainly didn't consider himself a misogynist. Considering how the word is applied across the internet, I can certainly understand how people feel that the best course of action still depends strongly on the actual content of the shirt, even if you personally feel it's objectively misogynistic.

Take the case of [Matt Taylor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matt_Taylor_%28scientist%29). To some, that shirt represents a fun, kitsch re-purposing of 1950s sci-fi pulp imagery. To others, it's a very public sign of how unwelcoming STEM fields can be for women. Again, Taylor probably didn't consider himself a mysogynist, but people have condemned this shirt in terms exactly as strong as those used in the question. (For what it's worth, I expect that in your case, the shirt was actually much more offensive. I googled "[mysogynistic t-shirt](https://www.google.com/search?q=mysogynistic+t-shirt&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAmoVChMIntbT1PXDyAIVhAgaCh1LSw60&biw=1440&bih=798#tbm=isch&q=misogynistic+t-shirt)", and there are certainly some horrendous examples there.)

Another case-in-point is the [punks of the late seventies](http://uk.complex.com/style/2013/05/29-things-you-didnt-know-about-punk-style/swastika-armband) wearing swastikas. They weren't Nazis, quite the opposite, but they felt they needed the strongest, most shocking symbol they could think of, to get the establishment angry. So if we imagine lecturing in the seventies, we could have a situation of a student wearing swastikas to class. That seems like the most clear-cut, unambiguous situation possible, but still, the student is not doing it for the reasons we think they are. And in fact getting angry, singling them out and getting security to escort them off the premises is just what they're hoping for.

People wear what they wear for strange and inscrutable reasons. For outsiders, a hijab may be a symbol of oppression, while for the wearer, it's actually a statement of emancipation. The same goes for t-shirts with movie posters, or death metal paraphernalia. Even swastikas. Of course, **things can still be offensive if they're not intended to cause offense**, but the lack of intent does change the situation, and what the best course of action is.

So let's take an extreme example: say a student comes to my class with a t-shirt that is absolutely shocking and reprehensible, and contains deeply disturbing imagery. Certainly, I would agree that something needs to be done, and it can't wait until the end of the lecture. So do I single him out in front of everybody, make a loud and public stand and force him to leave, possibly with the help of security? Or do I ask him to step outside with me and give him an opportunity to explain his reasons, and generally explain to him why I cant allow him back in?

Other answers have mentioned that the other students need to see that their safety is being guarded, and that the matter isn't iognored. Justice must be seen to be done, that sort of thing. Even so, I would still argue *against* the first strategy. I think there are three main reasons:

- If I single the student out, I will antagonize him, and strengthen his belief that he did nothing wrong. I will lose any chance of actually influencing his behavior. You may feel that he doesn't deserve such considerations, but if I want to actually change things for the better, I have to be pragmatic.
- As the responses here show, even if I think the issue is unambiguous, others may not. Especially with the misogynistic shirt, other students may take the side of the shirt-wearer. So while I'm making a stand and feeling good about myself, I'm actually creating a division in my classroom. This will make the atmosphere **less safe** in practice.
- The student may be suffering from something bordering on mental health issues. Perhaps a  compulsion to be socially inappropriate, or a deep self-loathing causing him to lash out at others in whatever way he can find.
- Finally, and I think most importantly, everybody has a fundamental right not to be *ascribed* an opinion. Even if the guy's covered in swastikas, he gets at least one chance to explain himself, and to do so in a non-public setting. I may be wrong in my interpretation, I may not. The point is, **everybody deserves at least on opportunity to explain themselves.** I think that's a fundamental right, and it's not lost simply because you wore something I didn't like, however objectionable it is.

Comment: To the downvoters: comments are welcome.

Comment: Tourettes does not involve a compulsion to shock. The end of this answer is fair, although it rather loses sight of the main problem which is the behaviour and its effects, rather than the intention. (I agree the latter may affect the best strategy.) But, really, the first 2 paragraphs invoke all the stereotypes about 'emotional' women getting upset over nothing and calling it 'misogyny'. The word is perfectly well-defined. This is true even if it is misused. Lots of words are misused. Do you routinely begin answers with the possibility that the asker may be misusing them?

Comment: @cfr I'm not saying that the word is misused, or that the OP didn't know what she was talking about. I'm saying that the word clouds discussion. It's a word that means different things to different people and yet carries a very strong emotional charge. Therefore, it's a good exercise to [taboo](http://lesswrong.com/lw/nu/taboo_your_words/) it and try to use more objective, and precise language. Specifically, to separate effect and intent. That way, we can have people legitimately being upset about a t-shirt, without inferring anything (either way) about the wearer's intention.

Comment: @cfr Fair point about Tourette's. The view of Tourette's as a compulsion to say socially unacceptable things is outdated. I've removed it from the answer.

Comment: I see now that my use of the word "emotionally" in the first paragraph invokes a stereotype of women responding  to instances of sexism "emotionally" and the fallacy of equating an emotional response with an irrational one. That was absolutely not my intention. I certainly didn't want to dismiss or diminish the OP's experience.

Comment: As I read it, 'misogynistic' describes the slogan and not the wearer's intent. I don't think that making the language developed to describe oppression - at considerable cost - off-limits is in anyway helpful. The language to name the problem is, frankly, a historical achievement. Lacking the terms to describe oppression has been - was for a long time, continues to be to some degree and some extent - itself part of the problem. There not being a word for a harm is an especially effective way of denying that there is any harm.

Comment: I didn't down vote your answer, by the way. I'm trying to explain why I suspect others did.

Comment: @cfr I agree that finding accepted names for patterns of oppression is very important milestone in emancipation. Nevertheless, the word misogyny implies dislike and contempt of women by any definition I can find, so calling someone or their actions misogynist, inevitably carries a personal charge. I didn't mean to imply that the words should banned ("taboo" was a poor phrase, but I was referring to the rhetorical exercise I linked), just that in specific contexts it's useful to unpack such words into more specific phrases, to get at the heart of the problem.

Comment: In any case, thanks for the insight into where the downvotes came from. I guess it's down to just the same kind of charged language I was trying to talk about :)

Comment: I don't disagree with anything you've said, and very strongly agree that 'misogynistic' is a problem word for the reasons you've stated-- it presumes something about the mindset or beliefs of the person being referred to and therefore invites argumentation/rebuttal/offense that is likely to derail any attempt at communication.  I was surprised at the downvotes too (I upvoted); I suspect it's because your answer, on the face of it, seems to be about defending the t-shirt wearer and not offering much in the way of possibilities for resolving or at least reframing the OP's problem.

Answer (score 5):

First step in any conflict should be communication. If I were in your shoes I would have likely go up to the person in question and ask them what message they want to convey by wearing that particular attire.

The reason I have this belief is that what constitutes offensive is **very** subjective, as one might take offense at anything really. Please note that I am not saying or implying that it was the case for OP, but without knowing the level of "offense" in question, it's hard to make a generalized judgement. In that case, it's always a good idea to *peacefully* confront the person and tell them that you feel offended. That's my first point.

The second point I would like to make is that the primary responsibility for sorting out your disagreements is on your own shoulders. It is in general frustrating to expect someone else to intervene and fight your battles for you. People of authority (the teacher in this case) might not notice the offense, or not realize how uncomfortable it makes you feel, unless you actually make that clear for everyone involved.

In the specific scenario that is depicted in the OP, I cannot imagine why you would not be allowed to point out that your classmate's attire is offensive and not suitable for public spaces, let alone a classroom. If the person reacts badly, then you have more of a case for disciplinary action against the classmate with the offensive clothing. Then the professor/TA/security and even other classmates would likely to be on your side.

If the person reacts in a favorable way (i.e. apologizing for the offense, and explaining that they did not mean to offend anyone) you have even taught your classmate something about good manners.

Comment: I believe it would not be constructive to post an offensive slogan on this site, even for illustrative purposes.

Comment: @ff524 of course not, I didn't mean that you should. I was just trying to explain that it's hard to know where on the scale from "tasteless humor" to "danger to society", this particular offense was.

Comment: If graffiti containing an unambiguous racial slur is posted in a public place, do you think the local authorities have no reason to intervene until someone complains? I don't think it should necessary be the "victim"'s responsibility to complain to an authority figure. (As the "victim" it can be very intimidating and difficult to speak up when someone is wearing clothing that is overtly hostile to you)

Comment: @ff524: If they aren't aware of it, how can they intervene? Your example is bad because there would have to be an investigation and finding the culprit would be hard. In OP's case, the shirt is worn by the offender so its obvious

Comment: @GIJoe If the professor doesn't see the shirt, I don't expect him to do anything. However, if he does see it and it is unambiguously offensive, I think as an authority figure he has some responsibility here.

Comment: @ff524: I haven't seen the message. Let's take a different route. What if the TA or Professor is TOO sensitive? What if a student wore a very US patriotic shirt to class and it offended say a small group of Iranians? Or what if the professor or TA is anti-military and finds it offensive that an ROTC student wears their uniform to class once a week? Point is it is very subjective so OP should tread lightly. There is no such thing as unambiguously offensive IMHO

Comment: @GIJoe I can _definitely_ think of things that are unambiguously offensive; e.g., widely known racial slurs.

Comment: @ff524: I tend to agree. My point is that its not offensive to everyone (e.g. those who are in on the joke, or tend to think that way). I don't wear that type of clothing.

Comment: @ff524 I have to disagree, if there is a whole sub-culture of using an unambiguously offensive racial slur in music/tv/sports/other entertainment (especially by the very people who would get offended by it) then it's apparently not as unambiguously offensive as one might think.

Comment: It's nothing remotely equivalent to the case in OP, of course, but for the sake of example consider that something like "Bacon is awesome" might be pretty damn offensive to politically active vegans, as it practically advocates for murder in their eyes. I happen to like bacon, and I might even wear a shirt like that (if I had one) that doesn't mean that I mean to offend every vegan that's around me.

Comment: "Bacon is awesome" is neither demeaning to, nor does it show hostility to, vegetarians. There's a difference between these examples and a slogan that is clearly meant to be hostile to a particular group. Showing approval for something some people don't like =/= showing hostility to certain people.

Comment: @ff524 I agree but I don't think the two examples of sub-culture are a good comparison, as Jews would not be inclined to use that kind of speech in songs/movies/books etc. At any rate I am not arguing that things should be tolerated. I am merely saying that if you are offended about something, not matter the "level of offense", speak up! let your voice be heard! that's the only way you can make a difference

Comment: OK, I agree that your answer would be helpful in a scenario where the message was offensive to me but not necessarily hostile. In my scenario (which of course you don't know the details of) I felt intimidated and traumatized by the hostility; I could not have said anything to the offender myself.

Comment: 'offensive' is extremely subjective. In general I would error on the side of free speech.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, teachers (including both professors and TAs) should absolutely intervene in such an instance.  As everyone else has said, non-discrimination policies would most likely prohibit such offensive misogynistic expression in a *classroom* environment, and these are policies with which I would recommend all teachers familiarize themselves before they enter the classroom.

Let me mention one more reason that you should not just overlook such an incident: **to prevent such things from happening in the future.** Not all students are completely familiar with what constitutes improper behavior in a classroom.  If nobody does anything, what's to stop that student from doing the same thing again?

Here's a related story from my own experience.  One time, when I was a TA for an engineering calculus course, I got an in-class group assignment back from a pair of students, where one student circled the other student's name and wrote "is gay" as a joke. Being gay myself, *I was pissed.* (I had also hoped that the idea that "gay" could be used an insult had gone out of acceptance by that time, in 2012. Guess not.) At the time, I didn't know who did it; it could've been someone outside the pair, but it certainly wasn't the student whose name was circled due to the handwriting being different.  I also didn't want to falsely accuse anyone, or put anyone on the spot.  I didn't quite frankly care who did it; I just wanted to make sure my students knew that this behavior was unacceptable.

So the next class, I read the university non-discrimination policy to *both* my classes and I told them what had happened, without naming anyone (or the class it happened in).  I said that I didn't care what anyone said or did in their free time, but in my class, I wouldn't stand for people doing things like this.

My first class, I couldn't hide my tension or my anger when I was saying all of this.  The second class, which was the one with these two students, I did the same thing, but I was much calmer because I had already done this with the first class.  The two students ended up apologizing to me when I handed back the paper, and I (calmly) said that I wasn't accusing anyone of doing anything, but I just needed to make sure that everyone understood that this wasn't acceptable.

In retrospect, the only thing I would have done differently in my case is *practice my speech beforehand* so I could convey the seriousness of what I was saying without the tension and anger I had during the first class.  (Some people don't react as well to tension and anger.)  That aside, I did feel good affirming for my students, some of whom were likely LGBT themselves, that my classroom was not a place where I would accept any such inappropriate or discriminatory behavior.  And finally, *I made it way less likely for anything similar to happen in the future on my watch*.

Your case is different, because it involves quite the open display of inappropriateness. In your particular case, I would walk up to the student and tell this person that wearing such a shirt in the class is inappropriate and goes against school policies, and that he needs to leave and change into something else before he returns to your class.  The students who are concerned about the shirt will most likely notice your action and feel relieved that you are addressing it.

I'm not so sure that you should call him out from the front of the classroom, although you certainly have the right to do so.  The student might find it humiliating to be called out in front of the entire class (especially in a large lecture), and moreover it's a little impersonal.  (Although I addressed my situation with the entire class, keep in mind that I didn't know who had done what and I didn't name anyone.  Also, if you just read the non-discrimination policy out loud in your case, it will be pretty obvious to everyone who you're addressing.)  I think the best outcome would be with a private or semi-private, direct conversation as I suggested above.

On the other hand, if you're intimidated and worried about possible physical violence, then you could opt to ask this person to leave in a semi-private manner but *with a reasonable physical distance between the two of you, while many other students are around*.  This allows for witnesses in case anything goes awry.  (This does seem like an unlikely scenario, but your safety is paramount.)  If this option is not safe enough to you, then as Pete L. Clark has suggested, you should call campus security and wait until they arrive before starting your class.

Answer (score 1):

> Should a professor intervene if a student in their class is wearing
>   clothing that is likely to be offensive and hostile to other students?
>   If so, how?

As with most things in life, it can be somewhat complicated. In professional settings rule of thumb is usually to "Praise in public, reprimand in private." Thus, while it may make sense for the professor to intervene, the best time to do so would likely be after class has concluded. How good or bad of an approach this might be in an academic setting might be up for debate, since a "teachable moment" might be lost for the rest of the class, but it also allows the student opportunity to save face.

Another thing of note along this lines, even more so since nobody else mentioned it, is that is also gives the professor a chance to check to make sure the student really understands the mean behind things. I've been in environments where ten to twenty percent or more of the students in a given class might be exchange students. Their cultural norms can be drastically different and they might not even fully understand what a slang term can mean. This allows for a much more robust conversation about things than just a "Don't wear that shirt again." being directed at the student.

> If yes: are there any scenarios in which a professor should not do
>   anything even though a student's clothes contains material that is
>   hostile towards another student or group of students?

This is likely going to be very subjective since the professor may not always be aware of the situation (e.g. quote in a foreign language, very large lecture hall where the professor can't even see the student, etc.). To a certain extent the student body needs to assist the faculty in being aware of some of the situations so they can be dealt with. Another scenario is protest campaigns to reclaim certain terms by effectively displaying those terms yourself. So at the end of the day, situations are going to arise, but likely it would need to be dealt with on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: this isn't a performance review. The shirt was seen in public. If you refrain from objecting to it in public then you are refraining from assuring the rest of the class that you will protect them from hateful speech. Letting it go and then discussing it privately might or might not prevent a recurrence, but it doesn't reassure any class members who were upset by it.

Comment: @KateGregory Except in academia we need to be mindful that not everyone is aware of our cultural norms. An exchange student might not have the faintest idea that a phrase is offensive or even what a word means so there is nothing gained by embarrassing them in front of the entire class. Plus, I would like to think that most people would catch on that if a student is asked to stay behind after class that they would know what the topic of discussion would be.

Answer (score -5):

I habitually wore Black metal T-Shirts, which can have offensive lines, as an Undergrad, which never got me into trouble. But, some people asked me why I like this kind of T-shirt and I tried to explain my reasoning.
This worked very well and I formed strong friendships with some of these people.

And I, personally, tried hard not to judge people from their appearances - which was never 100% sucessfull, but I think is a worthwile attempt.

So, I think the best first step is simply asking the person WHY he is wearing this t-shirt. Every person with a provacating T-shirt gets asked now and then, so it should be no big deal.
Running to your teachers first is similar to running to your mommy and not really grown up behaviour.
Disclaimer: I come from germany, where a much wider range of clothing is deemed acceptable in academia, especially social sciences and CS.

Comment: This fails to address the specifics of the question. The question refers to a t-shirt that was not just offensive but offensive toward a specific group (women) in a way that violated the school's rules against "discriminatory harassment." This was stated to be in the context of an engineering program; women are underrepresented in engineering, and it's important not to create a hostile atmosphere for them. If your heavy-metal shirt had, e.g., a satanist message, that's a different case, because although it might offend Christians, Christians are not an underrepresented group in engineering.

Comment: Regarding the specific shirt _you_ used to wear (not the shirt I encountered), Wikipedia says: "The T-shirt is banned in New Zealand, a handful of fans have faced court appearances and fines for wearing the shirt in public." (http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cradle_of_Filth)

Comment: @BenCrowell If satanists are underrepresented in engineering, does that mean that I must be careful not to offend them?

Comment: I'd like to -1 for "Running to your teachers first is similar to running to your mommy and not really grown up behaviour". This essentially makes yet another recourse unavailable to those who already feel victimized (and are uncomfortable with direct confrontation), by dissuading them from the only thing they can see to do (approach authority figures), and implying that they should feel bad about themselves for doing it.

Comment: @EricWilson: *If satanists are underrepresented in engineering, does that mean that I must be careful not to offend them?* Yes. But I'm not aware of any evidence that they're underrepresented. Ditto for atheists, left-handed people, or Albanians. When we talk about underrepresented groups, we're talking about groups that are underrepresented in proportion to their numbers in the general population.

Comment: @BenCrowell I'll agree that they are likely not significantly underrepresented, but I reject the notion that beliefs and actions should be protected on the basis of representation.

Comment: @BenCrowell A lot of the T-Shirts I have seen in my life could be constructed as offensive. Maybe not fashion but there are a lot of inmature T-shirts out there. Like "Dort - Mund" with an Arrow pointing towards the Penis (the joke only "works" in german). 
I personally would not see them as discriminatory but as inmature and act accordingly: talk to the person try to convince him that it's a bad idea. If that doesn't work, go to hihger places.

Comment: @ff524 Yes, but it is covered by free-speech laws in Germany. Ironically, many CDs of COF and effectively banned because they are not allowed for people under 18.

Comment: I just mentioned it because it sounds like it might be unwise to generalize from your "never got in trouble" experience (especially for those not in Germany)

Comment: I think it might be useful for everyone to read Ken White's essay on "Shirts and Shirtiness." http://www.popehat.com/2014/11/17/shirts-and-shirtiness/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+Popehat+%28Popehat%29

Comment: Under-represented is not the same as a history, or current risk, of discrimination. Despite historical prejudice against left-handed people, it is (as far as I know) now unlikely potential engineers are selected against because they are left-handed. Similarly, discrimination does not require under-representation. A single blind student in a class of 20 does not make blind students under-represented, but they may still face discrimination and I would be concerned about a t-shirt which might create an environment hostile to them. (Note: I pick this example deliberately.)